# How to save form data (not in database)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am making an application using ASP.NET MVC 3 which contains "form wizard", i.e. there are three forms which are wizards.

First form is for entering user details, second is for selecting product and third is for entering his payment details.

When the user enters his details in first form and goes to second form by clicking next submit button. And in the second form when the user selects the product, then his details from first form and his product choice from second form is sent to admin for approval. My question is that where should I save data from first and second form till users approval. When the user is approved then user data is saved to database. Where should I save form data when going from one form to other.

Comment: What do you mean by "sent to admin for approval?"  Is this a different system user?  If so, I don't know how you can do this without persisting it somewhere.

Comment: Okay, when submitting form for approval we'll have to save data in database. But what when the user is travelling from one form to other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JavaScript Way

Just because "form1" and "form2" look like two physically different forms doesn't mean they have to be. You can initially display the container for the first set of inputs, then when the user clicks next it hides the first and shows the second.

Once the user is finished with the second set of inputs the page submits both sets of fields to the server using one form. At this point it would need to go in a database or be emailed to someone for persistence.

### Traditional Way

If you need to have each form on a different page and submit between each one you could do it like this: (Note: this is a really bad way)
1. Form 1 submits
2. Server responds with form2 and data from form1 (to store in hidden fields on form 2)
3. User submits form2 (along with the hidden form1 data)